# Realm two way to insert element

Tags: java, android, database, realm

As far as I know, there is two way to insert element to database.

In first one, we can insert like this

```
realm.beginTransaction();
UsersTable usersTable = realm.createObject(UsersTable.class);
usersTable.setName(name);
usersTable.setSurname(surname);
usersTable.setAge(age);
usersTable.setSalary(salary);
realm.commitTransaction();
```

In second one, we have different kind of method to insert

```
realm.executeTransactionAsync(new Realm.Transaction () {
public void execute(Realm realm) {
//......
}
}, new Realm.Transaction.onSuccess() { 
public void onSuccess(Realm realm) { }
}, new Realm.Transaction.onError() {
public void onSuccess(Realm realm) { }
}
```

What is the difference between them? It seems like the bottom one gives option to indicate something on both success and error.

Answer (score 0):

```
realm.beginTransaction();
...
realm.commitTransaction();
```

This is synchronous transaction with no error handling (`catch(Throwable e) { realm.cancelTransaction();`). It is executed on the thread you are currently on.

---

```
realm.executeTransactionAsync(new Realm.Transaction () {
    public void execute(Realm realm) {
        //......
    }
}, new Realm.Transaction.onSuccess() { 
        public void onSuccess(Realm realm) { }
}, new Realm.Transaction.onError() {
        public void onSuccess(Realm realm) { }
}
```

This is asynchronous transaction. It can only be initiated from a Looper thread. It will run the transaction on Realm's background thread-pool.

The callbacks will be called only after Realm has updated the UI thread Realm.